# Can a vendor cancel an order due to a pricing error?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, commerce

I purchased some goods from a supplier which has now cancelled my order giving the reason as being a pricing error.

However I had paid for the item and in their online portal it stated that my order was accepted.

Do I have any legal rights in this case, as the terms and conditions don't state terms for acceptance of an order?

Also the [t's and c's don't address cancellations](https://www.serversplus.com/pdfs/serversplus_terms_and_conditions.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they can (by their contract) - Clause 3.1:

> The Seller reserves the right to amend prices at any time without prior notice. **Errors and omissions are excepted.**

However, it is possible that there are consumer protection laws in your jurisdiction that prohibit this. I think this is unlikely, however.

Comment: By that shouldn't they have notified me of the price increase and asked me if I wanted to continue with the order?

Comment: @P6345uk changing the price in the middle of the order, after you've paid, working out the new amounts, getting everything settled properly in accounts, is far more work than reasonably expected. The simpler and more effective and safer option for everybody is to cancel your order, inform you of why, and allow you to place a new order at the corrected price.

Comment: In the terms and conditions quote above, does it mean that "The seller reserves the right to amend prices UNLESS it is an error"?